# What are "invalid characters" in PDF passwords? "Password contains illegal characters"

Tags: macos, security, password, pdf, preview

I wanted to password-protect a PDF in Preview via the "Edit Permissions ..." dialog. I used a simple random password generator to create a reasonably secure password ... only to get it rejected with a "Password contains invalid characters" error message, repeatedly.

[image: Screen shot of dialog, with error message]

Through trial and error, I discovered that it actually doesn't like it when the password is too long. A 32-character password is fine, but a 33-character one produces this error.

This seems counter to many security recommendations, though. And arguably, the error message should tell you what's *actually* wrong; the current one is misleading. But I digress.

If there really are "illegal characters", which ones are they?

(I suppose it would be useful to understand whether the restrictions on allowed passwords are dictated by the actual PDF spec, or just an arbitrary bug which Apple could fix, but that's bonus points territory.)

I searched the Apple forums for any mention of this problem, but I seem to be the only one who is wondering about this. I also consulted Adobe's documentation for PDF Reader, but that doesn't mention any restrictions on allowable passwords, either.

This is on an up-to-date MacOS Monterey (12.5) installation.

Comment: Telling you what is actually wrong with a password would be leaking secrets about the password validation strategy

Comment: @PeterM How can I fix a password which is disallowed if the system doesn't tell me what's wrong with it? How does "password is too long" reveal anything secret?

Comment: By revealing "password too long", an attacker can incrementally shorten their test password word until that error disappears.  This then allows them to set known limits when brute forcing the actual password - and hence saves them a lot of work.

Comment: This is the dialog for _setting_ a password.

Comment: Technically this can still be applied in your case of creating the password.  In this case the attacker would creating PDF passwords in order to ascertain the maximum length when attacking your password.   Possibly you could consider this security theater, but if the password creation and validation code are the same code, then by not revealing anything other than yes/no it simplifies the code itself and removes a potential risk from teh coding point of view

Comment: But then the error message could simply be changed to something like "password is not acceptable" to avoid providing false information.

Comment: That's a different argument .. lol

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Section 7.6 of the PDF standard (ISO 32000) covers encryption.

https://www.iso.org/obp/ui/#iso:std:iso:32000:-2:ed-2:v1:en
(Ironically, you have to pay for a copy of an open standard.)

Passwords in the 1.7 standard are stored as a 32-byte string of characters in the Latin-1 Unicode range. (See "PDFDocEncoding, Annex D" of the standard.)

There are extensions (in the 2.0 standard) that allow all Unicode characters in a 127-byte string. Note that some Unicode chars are multi-byte.

Not all PDF viewers can parse the 2.0 standard.